# How do I cancel a batch process in Illustrator or Photoshop?

Tags: automation, batch-processing

I'm using the "batch..." automation process under the Actions menu in Illustrator. How do I cancel a batch process once it already started?

Is there a method for canceling batches in Photoshop as well?

Answer (score 6):

Hit the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key. It may take a moment for it to stop.

Comment: The escape key does not work. Nor does the keyboard cancellation combo (command period). In my experience you must force-quit the program.

Comment: You have to wait a while for it to stop. It doesn't happen immediately. It takes more than a few seconds.

Comment: I have clicked esc many times and waited a couple of minutes and it's still processing through - even as I write this. I think in some instances it doesn't work. I'm running an Image Processor batch.

Comment: @Daniel Mac or PC?

Comment: Good point, maybe it's because I'm on a Mac.

Comment: @Daniel it worked on a Mac, but this was a year ago since I've tried it. Maybe there's been an update.

Answer (score 0):

For me this doesn't work on a PC anymore – I'm afraid it may well be the good old <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Delete</kbd> (Task manager).